# Mapping in Python

Tags: python, mapping, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have at my dispositions a JSON list with all the bike stations called Velib in Paris with their latitude, longitude, number of bikes and capacity.

I am trying to calculate proportion `averages(number_of_bikes/bike_capacity)` of the number of bikes for the bike stations in different districts of Paris. I would like to create a mapping/function of a city that differentiates different districts(= so that when i put coordinates it sends me back the number or the district )  so that when i try to calculate an average per part of the city i can insert coordinates of the bike stations and it goes directly into the average of the number of bikes of the district it is in.

I can do it when the districts are parallel one to each other delimited by horizontal/ vertical strait lines.

```
for k in range(len(bike_station_list):
   if lat(bike_station_k)<lat_district_1 and   lng(bike_station_k <lng_disctrict_1

... and so on
```

However in reality Paris districts are far more complex.

How can I create a mapping of the city that can tell me in which district I am.

My first idea was to create a huge matrix with all longitudinal and latitudinal coordinates with the number of the district it is in but it looks a bit exaggerated.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Would the operative question be closest (in terms of time to get to) vs what district am I in? Closest is also far easier to calculate...

Comment: well i am trying to do a precise representation so i'd rather have the exact district - but i might as well try closest if it is too consuming

Comment: But suppose the closest is 100 meters across a district boarder and the district station is on the other side of the district?

Comment: well the thing is that i am trying to evaluate the influence of certain factors in a big area - but in order to do that i am starting with smaller areas which are in my case districts

Answer (score 2):

You can do get the district information by coordinate using Google's geocoding API

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=48.874809,2.396988

In the response:

```
{
    long_name: "20th arrondissement",
    short_name: "20th arrondissement",
    types: [
        "political",
        "sublocality",
        "sublocality_level_1"
    ]
}
```

See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding).
You'll be limited to 2500 free requests per day however (more if you pay) and you'll need to register an API key.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an approximate contour map of your districts, so the boundaries of the districts as a number of e.g. straight line segments. And then you need a way to find out if you're inside such a closed contour.

You'll find how to do that [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-know-a-point-is-inside-a-closed-curve-or-not)

Given the complexity of this algorithm, your large matrix isn't too bad an idea, if you're satisfied with a resolution of say 10 * 10 m. If you want to cover an area of say 30 * 30 km that would be 3000 * 3000 == 9,000,000 squares. Nothing a PC can't easily handle, including the searches involved.

Comment: do you know where i can find such matrixes or do i have to make it by hand ?

Comment: If  you have a colored (by district) paper map of Paris, some preprocessing would get you in business. Take a picture, read it in memory using PIL or Pillow, compute average colors from a number of adjacent pixels and reduce the size by spatially sampling it (taking one out of every x * y pixels, so 1 pixel per 10m x 10m area.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find the coordinates for the vertices of a polygon that approximates Paris' districts, then this reduces to a [point-in-polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) problem. You can use the ray-casting or the winding number algorithm to solve it, as mentioned in that article.